# ImageButtons size in different densities

Tags: android, android-widget

Well, I have some issues showing ImageButtons in different dpi devices:

For example, If I have a .png button with 150x60 px. And try to use that button in my app, using `layout_height = wrap_content` and `layout_width = wrap_content` the button seems to look bigger in a hdpi device.
To show the button in the real size I have to convert the size to dpi, for example:
`layout_height = 100dp` and `layout_width = 40dp`

But I'm not very comfortable using hardcoded values in sizes.

I'm doing something wrong?

Many thanks for the help. And Sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I decided to use 9-patch drawables to draw buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually I create three different sizes of my button images and store them in the res/drawable-ldpi, res/drawable-mdpi and res/drawable-hdpi to be used for low, medium and high density screens.  This is discussed in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: Thanks Alan, I know how to set alternative resources. But my problem is why using wrap_content shows the image bigger than real size.

Comment: Oh, I guess I misunderstood your question then.  What do you mean by bigger than real size exactly?